# Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{| \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \sqrt{k}|}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We are asked to compute

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \displaystyle\frac{| \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \sqrt{k}|}{\sqrt{n}}$

This appears to converge to $0.5$ by numerical evidence . I tried squeeze theorem but to no avail.